# Should we use Material-UI with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to design a login page in react and found material-ui, now question is should be use Material-UI? Also, in following examples how I can put styles in a separate file? I think it should be put in some `.css` file if yes then how following code could be put in `css` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 200,
    },
  },
}));

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard" />
      <TextField id="filled-basic" label="Filled" variant="filled" />
      <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Ref: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-guyt6 index.js

Answer (score 3):

You can create a file next to your `BasicTextFields.jsx`, called `styles.jsx`. I would not add the styling into a `CSS` in this case.

In `styles.jsx` you could have the following:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 200,
    },
  },
}));

export default useStyles;
```

Then simply import in your component as the following:

```
import useStyles from './styles';

export default function BasicTextFields() {
   const classes = useStyles();

   return (
       ...
   );
}
```

Important part is that you need to use `const classes = useStyles()` inside your component. If you use outside you will get `Invalid hook call.` error message.

At least that's what I have in my side project. I hope this helps!

Comment: it give me error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app


any idea ?

Comment: Just updated my answer why it was happening, usually the reason for that is using `useStyles()` outside of the component, please find it above. Hope that helps!

Comment: I already did tht but trick did work for me, and then I slept thinking I must uninstall npm node and other things and reinstall, and yet I dont know if it would work