# Material UI: Is it possible to put the makeStyle styles in a separate file?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would be happy to be able to put the Hook API styles in a separate file for cleanliness purposes.

Do you know if it is possible and how it can be done? I didn't find anything aobut it in the official docs and everything I've tried has failed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we use Material-UI with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331002/should-we-use-material-ui-with-react) The title a bit misleading in the mentioned question but in the answer there is way to separate the styling as you want.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`makeStyles` returns you a `useStyles` hook that you call within your functional component. You can definitely move it out into a separate file and import the useStyles hook

styles.js

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: props => props.color,
  },
});

export { useStyles };
```

component.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {useStyles} from './styles.js'
export default function MyComponent(props) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return <div className={classes.root} />;
}
```

Comment: What naming convention should be followed for the file containing CSS code?

Comment: styles.js or since you're returning a hook it can be useStyles.js

Comment: How can we achieve the same in react with typescript and MUI5

Comment: Can we implement the same in MUI5 ?